# SQLITE_ERROR: near ">": syntax error when no ">" is used

Tags: node.js, typescript

`SQLITE_ERROR: near ">": syntax error`

This is what I get after I try this

```
function findAccount(id) {
  var account;
  db.all(`SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE INTERNAL_ID = ${id}`, [], (err, rows) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err.message);
    rows.forEach((row) => {
      account = JSON.stringify(row);
    })
  });
  return account;
}
```

${id} contains only an integer. There was never > used here at all.
How to make this work? I use node.js sqlite3 and typescript

Thanks

I was expecting a row from the database. But i got nothing except from this error.